# Install multiple packages via different methods in one Yum command

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management, yum

Is it possible to group these three commands into one?

```
yum install emacs
yum groupinstall "Virtualization"
yum localinstall /tmp/hello.rpm
```

I'd like to install a number of packages using all three methods above in a script but would like it to be a single operation so that the user only has to answer `y` one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have worked around this by listing what packages are installed by the Virtualization Yum group with `yum group info "Virtualization"`. Then, the `localinstall` subcommand has actually been deprecated and the regular `install` command works for installing local RPMs. Thus, I managed to specify all packages in a single `yum install` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum shell
```

is the generic way to do this. But "install" itself can install local files and/or groups (yum install @grp).